# Extract specific token out of ANTLR Parse Tree

Tags: java, kotlin, antlr, antlr4

i'm trying to extract data from the ANTLR parse tree, but not fully grasping how this should be done correctly

Let's say i have the following two SQL queries:

```
        // language=SQL
        val sql3 = """
        CREATE TABLE session(
            id           uuid                    not null
                constraint account_pk
                    primary key,
            created     timestamp   default now() not null
        )
        """.trimIndent()

        // language=SQL
        val sql4 = """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah(
                id           uuid                    not null
                constraint account_pk
                    primary key,
                created     timestamp   default now() not null
            )
        """.trimIndent()
```

Now i parse both of them:

```
        val visitor = Visitor()
        listOf(sql3, sql4).forEach { sql ->
            val lexer = SQLLexer(CharStreams.fromString(sql))
            val parser = SQLParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer))

            visitor.visit(parser.sql())
            println(visitor.tableName)

        }
```

In my visitor if i visit the tableCreateStatement, i get the parse tree, but obviously just grabbing child1 will work for `sql3`, but not for `sql4` since child1 in `sql4` is `IF NOT EXISTS`

```
class Visitor : SQLParserBaseVisitor<Unit>() {

    var tableName = ""

    override fun visitCreate_table_statement(ctx: SQLParser.Create_table_statementContext?) {
        tableName = ctx?.getChild(1)?.text ?: ""
        super.visitCreate_table_statement(ctx)
    }

}
```

Is there a way to find a specific token in the parse tree?

I'm assuming the payload has something to do with it, but since it's of type `Any`, i'm not sure what to check it against

```
    override fun visitCreate_table_statement(ctx: SQLParser.Create_table_statementContext?) {
        ctx?.children?.forEach {
            if (it.payload.javaClass == SQLParser::Schema_qualified_nameContext) {
                tableName = it.text
            }
        }
        super.visitCreate_table_statement(ctx)
    }
```

**EDIT**: the .g4 files are from
https://github.com/pgcodekeeper/pgcodekeeper/tree/master/apgdiff/antlr-src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work

```
    override fun visitCreate_table_statement(ctx: SQLParser.Create_table_statementContext?) {
        ctx?.children?.forEach {
            if (it.payload.javaClass == Schema_qualified_nameContext::class.java) {
                tableName = it.text
            }
        }
        super.visitCreate_table_statement(ctx)
    }
```

For branching trees

```
    fun walkLeaves(
        childTree: ParseTree = internalTree,
        leave: (childTree: ParseTree) -> Unit) {

        if (childTree.childCount == 0) {
            if (!childTree.text?.trim().isNullOrBlank()) {
                leave(childTree)
            }
        } else {
            for (i in 0 until childTree.childCount) {
                walkLeaves(childTree = childTree.getChild(i), leave = leave)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
fun extractSQL(
    childTree: ParseTree,
    tokens: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
): String {

    walkLeaves(childTree = childTree) { leave ->
        tokens.add(leave.text)
    }

    ...

}
```